# Can't add custom script (leaflet) to Contact page

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, contact-form

I'm trying to add a map in Contact page. In order to do that,I did the following:

In file: `app/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml` I added:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="cms_page_layout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Contact</title>
        <css src="css/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="js/leaflet.js" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Files are indeed added in page's `<head>`.

Then in:
`app/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/Magento_Contact/templates/map.phtml` I added:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery'], function($){
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         var map = L.map('mapid').setView([40.591110, 23.037170], 15);
    });
})
</script>
```

The last thing I tried was to wrap the code between `require(['jquery'], function($){ ...... })` in `leaflet.js` file.

Based on similar issues, this should be enough to have the script working. But instead of that I'm getting javascript error in page:

```
ReferenceError: L is not defined
```

Please let me know if anyone.

---

---

-----SOLUTION BASED ON @PRINCE ANSWER----

`app/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="cms_page_layout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Contact</title>
        <css src="css/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="js/leaflet.js" />
    </head>
</page>
```

`app/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/Magento_Contact/templates/map.phtml`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'leaflet', 'my-custom-contact-js'], function($, L, scriptContact) {
        scriptContact();
    });
</script>
```

`app/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/Magento_Contact/web/js/custom-js-contact.js`

```
define(['jquery','leaflet'], function($,L) {
    return function scriptContact() {
        Your js content goes here.
    }
});
```

`app/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'my-custom-contact-js' : 'Magento_Contact/js/custom-js-contact'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        'leaflet': 'js/leaflet',
    },
    shim: {
        leaflet: {
            exports: 'L'
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Don't add js like this, in Magento 2 the recommended way is to use **requirejs**.

So to do it via `Requirejs` :

> app/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'my-custom-contact-js' : 'Magento_Contact/js/custom-js-contact' //without the extension .js
        }
    }
};
```

> app/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/Magento_Contact/web/js/custom-js-contact.js

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    "use strict";
    return function scriptContact() {
        Your js content goes here.
    }
});
```

> app/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/Magento_Contact/templates/map.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'my-custom-contact-js'], function($, scriptContact) {
        scriptContact();
    });
</script>
```

Remove the **content** of : `var/view_preprocessed`.

Run : `php bin/magento cache:clean`, `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

And congratulation, your script is loaded successfully.

Comment: Your code and my code too. work ok the first time page is loaded.The error is occuring after refreshing page. If I delete magento cache, script works ok only the first time page is loaded. Any ideas about that?

Comment: Which error ? Can you share it ?, you told that your code works too. It's not the good way. And i think this error occure because you have added before some js like your exemple !

Comment: error `ReferenceError: L is not defined`

Comment: this is the error that makes script not working properly at first place

Comment: `L` function is defined in file leaflet.js, which is loaded in page, so this error makes no sense

Comment: This error is not related to my solution, i pretty sure in 90% because you have added some inline js or like your exemple, this is why i told that the best way is to use requirejs

Comment: I have tried your code and it works the same way. I know it's a better solution, but the error is still there. There's no inline code, I have moved it in `custom-js-contact.js` just as you suggested. I think that something needs to be done with the leaflet.js file, because the function is in there. You can take a look of the file here https://files.fm/u/n44eeqtw

Comment: I think I found the solution, please see the updated description

Comment: `<script src="js/leaflet.js" />` in `contact_index_index.xml` should not be here, I told you to use require to ass custom script, js, library ...