# custom script (leaflet) in Contact page

Tags: magento2, module, script

I added Leaflet map to contact page like here:
[Can't add custom script (leaflet) to Contact page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248896/cant-add-custom-script-leaflet-to-contact-page)

I used the solution with success. If you want to put it into an extension (not just in a theme):

contact_index_index.xml:

```
<css src="<Vendor>_<module>::leaflet/leaflet.css" />
<script src="<Vendor>_<module>::leaflet/leaflet.js" />
```

I did place all leaflet files in a seperate directory in app/code/view/frontend/web/leaflet to get it seperated from other code and to get it independend from themes.

But I got a Javscript Error in the console:

```
"Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(t){..."
```

Site is working as expected, but I would like it to work without errors to avoid future problems. As far as I see this error is from require.js but how do I fix it the right way preferable without modifications to the leaflet.js files?

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the Leaflet JS Library in your `requirejs-config.js`.

Example:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'leaflet': 'js/leaflet',
            'markercluster': 'js/leaflet.markercluster'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        'leaflet': {
            exports: 'L'
        },
        'markercluster': {
            deps: ['L']
        }
    }
};
```

And add your map in a your phtml :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        "jquery",
        "leaflet"
    ], function ($, L) {
        $(function () {
            // Add your leaflet map here
            // Documentation : https://leafletjs.com/examples
        });
    });
</script>
```